# how to pipe an upload file to another server

Tags: sails.js

I have two server. server1 will recieve upload request from user and pipe that request to server2 to upload file to server2. Here is my code for server1

```
upload: function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.headers);
        console.log(req.body);
        req.pipe(request.post('http://localhost:1337/file/upload')).pipe(res);
}
```

and here is code for server2:

```
upload: function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.allParams());
        console.log(req.file());
        console.log(req.headers);
        if (req.file("mot")) {
            req.file('mot').upload({
                    dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'data')
                }, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.json({
                            failed: true
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("file uploaded");
                        return res.ok();
                    }
                }
            )
        }else{

        }
    }
```

when is use postman to send upload request directly to server2 it work. but when i send request to server1 i got this error on server2:

```
{ Error: ETIMEOUT: An Upstream (`mot`) timed out waiting for file(s). No files were sent after waiting 10000ms.
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/media/thanhtv/Data/bitbucket/nodejs/test/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/Upstream.js:62:15)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  message:
   'ETIMEOUT: An Upstream (`mot`) timed out waiting for file(s). No files were sent after waiting 10000ms.' }
```

please help me out. i'm using sails.

Comment: can someone give me a guide please